# post html form in json format using ajax to Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, json

I have the below html form, which I would like to post to a url using ajax in JSON format,

I am unable to receive the response in Django (backend), please advise where I am going wrong.

Here is my html form.

```
    <form id ="addressform" >
    <input type="text" name="DoorNo" id="text-basic" value="" placeholder="Door no.">   
    <input type="text" name="BuildingName" id="text-basic" value="" placeholder="Building/Road Name">        
    <button type="submit" onclick="addressform()" >Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Here is my jQuery

```
function addressform() {                    
                        var data = $('#addressform').serializeArray();
                        $.post('/suggestions', data);
                       }
```

Here is my function in views.py in Django (backend).

```
def suggestions(request):
   data = json.loads(request.body)
   #print data
   return HttpResponse( json.dumps({"status" : 1}) )
```

Comment: the data should be in the request.POST dictionary.

Comment: what kind of error do you get (if any)? Do you even receive data in the view?

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the URL above that you direct to?

```
function addressform() {    
    $.ajax({
        url : "{% url 'app:your_view' %}",
        type: "POST",
        data: { ... },

        success : function(json) {
            //success!
            console.log(json);

        },

        error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
            // what to do it there is an error
            }
        });
    };
})
```

Also depending on the version of python you are using. You could use

```
return JsonResponse(data_you_want)
```

I'm a little confused as to what you're doing in your view...